# Etymology of “Grager”

Tags: purim, words, yiddish, etymology

What is the Etymology of “Grager”?

Grager is the noisemaker we use on Purim during the Megila when Haman's name is read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Merriam Webster Dictionary online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grager) it is from the Polish word grzegarz, meaning rattle.

My knowledge of the polish language is non-existent, but the dictionaries I found online (such as [this one](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-polish/rattle)) didn't translate rattle that way. See [here](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-polish/rattle) for many different polish words for the word rattle.

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/?hl=en#en%7Cpl%7Crattle) has tons of different words for the word rattle.

You can listen to the pronunciation of Polish words [here](http://oddcast.com/home/demos/tts/tts_example.php?sitepal).

Comment: The similar _Grzegorz_ is the Polish for _Gregor_ (or _Gregory_). Well, similar to my eyes. Perhaps a Pole would say they're very dissimilar. Interestingly, such names come from a Greek word meaning "awake, watchful", or possibly "fast, quick"; that there might be a descendant meaning "rattle" is not (to my lay mind) farfetched.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an [onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomonopia) to me.